# Diagnose/fix solid black rectangle filling plot in R for 2 factor variables

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R and am plotting 2 factor variables, each of length 226666, as plot(variable1, variable2).  I am getting a solid black rectangle filling the graph as output rather than the scatterplots that I normally see as output. I have never tried to plot a dataset of this size. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Try plotting the first 10 elements ( `plot(variable1[1:10], variable2[1:10])` ), then 100, 1000, 10000, 100000. I suspect you will see that the solid black rectangle is actually 226666 circles.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  When I segment the variables as suggested going from 1:10 then 1:100 then 1:1000, it plots multiple horizontal gray rows with the bottom row the darkest and the top row the lightest shade of gray.  When I increase from 10 to 1000 and so on the rows get sequentially darker until the entire graph is a solid black rectangle.  Do you know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I figured it out.  There were some T and F hidden within one of my factor variables that were the cause of this output.  Once I changed them to numbers my output became a normal scatterplot.